# Why "auto" cannot accept braced-init-list when deducing return value?

Tags: c++, list, initialization, c++14, auto

[Modern Effective C++] says:

```
template<class T>
void f(T t){}
int main(){
    f({1,2,3});
}
```

Will fail compilation, because when template instantiation, the type of T must be known, while here {1,2,3} is braced-init-list. Should fix like:

```
auto x={1,2,3};//auto deduces x to std::initializer_list
f(x);
```

I could understand this, but then my question:

Why the book continues to say, when using "auto" for return value deduction, it cannot accept and deduce braced-init-list?

```
auto f()
{
    return {1,2,3};
}
```

Will fail compilation.

Emmmmm, if this is part of C++14 standard, I don't understand why there's such a restriction?And it continues to say:

```
auto resetV=[&v](const auto& newValue){v=new Value;}
```

The "auto" before "newValue" cannot accept {1,2,3} either. Why we have such 2 restrictions?

I guess maybe from language design perspective, there'll be some confusions when doing type deduction? Just a guess.
Any clues of these design decisions? It has confused me for days.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::initializer_list` is a reference to an anonymous array.

The array itself lives at block scope where the `initializer_list` was created.

```
std::initializer_list<int> f() {
  return {1,2,3};
}
```

is almost completely useless, because the array's lifetime is the body of `f`, and the `initializer_list` that refers to it exists in a nearly completely disjoint period of code.

Using that `initializer_list` is going to almost certainly be undefined behavior.  You could probably ask its size and if it is empty, and that might be defined behavior (don't know, don't care enough to check), but you definitely cannot examine its contents.

Initializer lists are references to the data, not copies of the data.

If:

```
auto f() {
  return {1,2,3};
}
```

deduced itself to be the above, it would be almost never useful.

The exception, that `auto x = {1,2,3};` works, is the one and only case where `initailizer_list<int>` can be deduced from a set of `{}`.  (In C++11, the same was true of `auto x{1};`, but that was depricated).

Answer (score 1):

> Why the book continues to say, when using "auto" for return value deduction, it cannot accept and deduce braced-init-list?

It's not that it "can't deduce it". It's just not allowed. Think carefully about this code:

```
#include <initializer_list>

auto f() -> std::initializer_list<int>
{
    return {1,2,3};
}
```

Does it compile? Yes. Is it safe? No. This could potentially introduce all kinds of problems with the lifetime of the underlying array. `std::initializer_list` shouldn't be used like a container.

Comment: Not just "potentially". That array is an ex-array as soon as you leave the function.

Comment: The return type is a copy of the initializer_list object, so why it is an ex-array? Thanks